# How to get the default namespace when parsing an XML document?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to parse an XML file (using VB.Net) and get the default namespace of the root element to add to a XMLNamespaceManager that will be applied to a different XML object.

I have tried several methods, but none have worked. The code snippet below is my most recent attempt:

```
Dim rdlXml As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
rdlXml.Load(reportDir & "/" & report & ".rdl")

Dim root As XmlNode = rdlXml.DocumentElement

Dim nsMgr as System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager = new System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(rdlXml.NameTable)
nsMgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty,root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix(String.Empty))
```

This code does not seem to successfully add the namespace to nsMgr.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I am using .NET 2.0

Comment: A root does not have a namespace prefix.  The namespace is usually defined in the root node so you have to get the namespace of the root, not the prefix of the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `nsMgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty, root.NamespaceURI)`

Comment: Hi FloatingKiwi; your code-answer might be useful, but it would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why these proposed changes would resolve the questioner's problem. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.